# Epoch time to struct tm conversion in C

Tags: c

I have input time in seconds epoch format. 
I need to have struct tm out of this epoch time in seconds.

```
    struct tm epoch_time;
    int seconds = 1441852;
    epoch_time.tm_sec = seconds;
```

My purpose is to have tm structure filled with proper values for years, months, days, hours, minutes, and seconds for the given epoch time in seconds. Any hint in this regard will be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
struct tm epoch_time;
time_t seconds = 1441852;
memcpy(&epoch_time, localtime(&seconds), sizeof (struct tm));
```

This assumes you want local time. If you want GMT, use `gmtime` instead of `localtime`. Note that this will crash on error.

Comment: `localtime_r` is cleaner, where available.

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard Agreed.

Comment: it seems input to localtime() should be in milliseconds rather than seconds.

Comment: @Omkar No, it should be in seconds since the epoch.